# CSS Input Type Selectors - Possible to have an "or" or "not" syntax?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If they exist in programming),

If I have an HTML form with the following inputs:

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="password" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

I want to apply a style to all inputs that are either `type="text"` or `type="password"`.

Alternatively, I would settle for all input's where `type != "checkbox"`.

It seems like I to have to do this:

```
input[type='text'], input[type='password']
{
   // my css
}
```

Isn't there a way to do:

```
input[type='text',type='password']
{
   // my css
}
```

or

```
input[type!='checkbox']
{
   // my css
}
```

I had a look around, and it doesn't seem like there is a way to do this with a single CSS selector.

Not a big deal of course, but I'm just a curious cat.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 247, accepted):

CSS3 has a pseudo-class called [:not()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation)

```css
input:not([type='checkbox']) {    
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>If <code>:not()</code> is supported, you'll only see the checkbox.</p>
                                      
<ul>
  <li>text: (<input type="text">)</li>  
  <li>password (<input type="password">)</li>       
  <li>checkbox (<input type="checkbox">)</li> 
 </ul>
```

#### Multiple selectors

As Vincent mentioned, it's possible to string multiple `:not()`s together:

```css
input:not([type='checkbox']):not([type='submit'])
```

CSS4, which is [supported in many of the latest browser releases](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list), allows multiple selectors in a `:not()`

```
input:not([type='checkbox'],[type='submit'])
```

#### Legacy support

All modern browsers support the CSS3 syntax. At the time this question was asked, we needed a fall-back for IE7 and IE8. One option was to use a polyfill like [IE9.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231706/ie9-js-has-something-else-rendered-it-obsolete). Another was to exploit the cascade in CSS:

```
input {
   // styles for most inputs
}   

input[type=checkbox] {
  // revert back to the original style
} 

input.checkbox {
  // for completeness, this would have worked even in IE3!
}
```

Comment: nice one! thanks. is that CSS3 selector fully supported? (i only really care about IE7+, FF3+, Safari recent, Chrome recent)

Comment: It's supported in IE9+ and all other modern browsers. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t37

Comment: For the sake of completeness if you want to do multiple "not"s then this is the syntax to use:  input:not([type='checkbox']):not([type='submit'])

Answer (score 31):

```
input[type='text'], input[type='password']
{
   // my css
}
```

That is the correct way to do it. Sadly CSS is not a programming language.

Comment: You could use Less CSS or Sass, though.

Comment: Less, yes! I love it.