# AngularJS chekbox ng-required

Tags: angularjs

i have some `checkboxes` that need to be `checked` when the user `click` the `submit` button.
i have insert this `ng-required="cbmemberdoc.checked"` but seems that is not working.

and this in the css

```
 input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
```

on submit button i have this:

```
ng-disabled="client.$invalid"
```

This works fine with others fileds like textbox it becames red when the user pass it without any text but not the checkbox

Comment: Could you make plunkr ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the input element in a `span`, and apply the border to that `span` element. Here are the CSS changes.

**CSS:**

```
.error-wrapper{
  display:inline-grid;
  border:2px solid transparent;
}
.error{
  border:2px solid red;
}
.error-wrapper input{
  margin:0px;
}
```

Below is a demo for the same.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.array = [false, false, false, false, false];
});
```

```css
.error-wrapper{
  display:inline-grid;
  border:2px solid transparent;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:2px;
  padding-left:3px;
}
.error{
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:2px;
  padding-left:3px;
}
.error-wrapper input{
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app='myApp'>
  <form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <span class="error-wrapper" ng-class="{'error': myForm.test1.$invalid}">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="array[0]" name="test1" required>
    </span>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i thin you are using html5 validaion not angularjs since i ddint see novalidate tag and ng-rquired but i will see

Comment: in my form i have this  <form class="form-horizontal" name="test" novalidate> in the begging

Comment: is not possible to put the checkbox rounded red instead of a square arround it?

Comment: @hpt Well if you know CSS you can do `border-radius:50%` check my updated answer!

Comment: i think you css could be replaced by   input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
            border: 2px solid red;
            outline-color: red;

Comment: @hpt You cannot have border red for input element which is checkbox, that is why I changed my answer to this!

Comment: i will test it but i think the circle on checkbox is a good option
but what you think if i replace with   input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
            border: 2px solid red;
            outline-color: red;

because i have other inputs like textbox's

Comment: @hpt leave the code for text boxes as it is, you can use the CSS `:not` selector to apply to all input tags except the checkboxes. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445533/css-input-type-selectors-possible-to-have-an-or-or-not-syntax)

Comment: so i should use :not on other css than yours?

Comment: @hpt Change that css class to `input:not([type='checkbox']).ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
` Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anopne6g/) demoing the CSS

Comment: i see that with span tag the text in the textbox is not very well align

Comment: @hpt Dude i get that you want this fixed but can't you play around with it, I just wanted to help you solve this small issue, dont make me your employee and work for you!

Comment: @hpt i dont know what is the exact issue, but if you change the padding property of the input element, itll get solved

Comment: is Just the text and the checkbox is not aligned

Comment: Your code works fine!!
However if you pu some text on the checkbox it get a red ballon over the text also and not just on the cb.
i will try to fix it 
Thanks